# JSDoc3 - Tidy organization of object literals

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm an absolute newcomer to JSDoc and the Javadoc-like conventions; I am looking for some low-hanging fruit to get up and running, and I'm coming up short.

My code is organized like this, primarily as a matter of personal style:

```
var app = app || {};

app.ui = {
  someUIfunction: function() {},
  someUIparams: {},
  anotherFunction: function(string, object) {}
}

app.rest = {
  someRESTCall: function(url,data) {},
  someRESTparams: {},
  moreRESTCall: function(url,data) {}
}
```

Theoretically everything could just be one monolithic object under "app", but I like breaking down the next-level objects separately for handy cold-folding and searching in the IDE. Plus it just feels tidy to me that way.

What I cannot manage to do is drill down into the third-level functions and objects. JSDoc3 doesn't seem to want to render it for me; moreover, I'm not in love with having a starting page that is just "app" (or whatever I give the app in the end) as the namespace... I want its members to be in the index as well. Here's my attempt (forgive the silly examples!):

```
/**
 * Application Namespace for this marvellous application
 * 
 * @namespace app
 */
var app = app || {};

/**
 * An object containing methods and parameters used for UI presentation logic
 * 
 * @type {object}
 * @memberOf app
 * @property {string} title - a string used as the title of the UI
 * @property {function} init - a function to initialize the UI
 */
app.ui = {
  // not bothering to document this for whatever reason
  title: "some title",
  /**
   * @memberOf app.ui
   * @params {object} params - an object containing necessary initialization parameters
   */
  init: function(params) {
    // some initialization logic
  }
}
```

There are two problems:

1. Ideally I'd like app.ui to have its own page. Is @namespace the right way to do this? It works, but visually it masquerades in the Index as being at the same level as app itself.
2. app.ui.init isn't documented at all.

It seems to me (and admittedly, this is probably just ignorance!) that JSDoc3 would be happier if I were to use:

```
app.ui.init = function() {} // (etc)
```

But that's going to be rather ugly as far as I'm concerned. Any pointers for the syntax I need to use to indicate nested members is what I'm after.